# unity3d: A ring hanging from a horizontal pipe

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a problem in Unity3d.
I have a horizontal pipe and a ring. The ring's position is to be around the pipe. As I play the scene, the ring keeps falling down and passing through the pipe. I need the ring to have the physics and gravity properties and at the same time being hanged from the pipe, not passing through the pipe?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It's a well known problem in game physics!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the collider on the pipe, simply one long cylinder collider.

**Here is the trick for the ring:**

Say the ring has diameter 10 meters, and the thickness of the ring-metal is 1m.  (So the circumference is about 32 meters.)

Do this: make a **simple sphere collider** **one meter diameter**.  ie same as the ring metal-thickness.

**Put it "inside" the ring.**  Duplicate it say 20 times and spread those evenly around the ring.

(Of course, the number of ball colliders you need will vary with how thick the ring-metal is compared to the circumference. You do not need to "pack them in tightly" - experiment.)

Depending on your situation, this can work beautifully.  Give it a try.